# Choosing typeface for verb

Tags: fontspec, verbatim, typefaces

How can I change the typeface used by `\verb`?

I currently have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Mono}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\verb|foo bar baz|

\end{document}
```

The first paragraph (*Lorem…*) gets typeset with Roboto Mono, but the second paragraph (*foo…*) gets the default fixed-width typeface.

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you just want to change `\verb` or change monospace generally eg `\texttt{..}` ?

Comment: I would be okey with changing the monospace font in general.

Comment: `\setmonofont{Roboto Mono}`

Comment: You should remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` from your preamble if you're using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you comrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using these two lines:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Roboto Mono}
```